# C# Set Color for 1 Cell in DataGridView

Tags: c#, mysql, database, datagridview

iam looking for a method to set the color specific only for 1 cell by clicking on it.

I build a Canteen Voter, which you can choice between 4 menues each day.

My DataGridView is connected to a database from which it receives all information and when you click on a cell it is also stored in the database for the logged-in user.

**Now I would like to be able to color the cells individually when clicking.**

So far I only found the SelectedCells property, but this actually only sets a color for "SelectedCells" when these cells lose focus again they are white again.

I would have liked them to be able to keep this color to make it even clearer to the user which dish he had just chosen.

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should set `DataGridViewCell.Style` property.

Take a look at this example

```
private void DataGridView1_CellClick(object sender, DataGridViewCellEventArgs e)
{
    if (e.RowIndex < 0 || e.RowIndex == dataGridView1.NewRowIndex)
    {
        return;
    }
    var dataGridViewCellStyle = 
        new DataGridViewCellStyle(dataGridView1.DefaultCellStyle)
    {
        BackColor = Color.Gold
    };
    dataGridView1[e.ColumnIndex, e.RowIndex].Style = dataGridViewCellStyle;
}
```

Comment: Quick and Fast, thanks

Comment: Maybe you have also a solution for my next function. Each time i click on a Row, the whole Row should be recolored white before remark a specific cell on the same row to green.